# Jhipster Spring backend - Social login & React Native frontend

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, jhipster, google-signin

I have created Spring as backend and enabled social login for google authentication. `/signin/google` is the endpoint with a method `POST` and content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`.

Postman client works perfectly fine if i invoke the above mentioned endpoint from postman client(Google chrome app) it gives me 200 status code and **JSESSIONID** and i am able to invoke the other secure api.

but for react native i am unable to execute it. Help would be highly appreciated. Mentioned below is the function that i am using to trigger google signin.

```
googleSignin = () => {
      var data = 'scope=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
      axios({
        url: baseUrl + 'signin/google',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        config: {
          headers:
          {
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true
          },
          credentials: "same-origin"
        },
        withCredentials: true
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log('googleSignin res() ---> ', res.headers);

        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    };
```

It always gives me CORS error policy. mentioned below is the cors configuration on the backend.

```
allowed-origins: "*"
allowed-methods: "*"
allowed-headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"
exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
allow-credentials: true
max-age: 1800
```

and screenshot is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a `cross-domain` issue. After `jQuery` 1.5.0 and later, the `cross-domain` was blocked. As a result, the following error occurs when requested by `ajax`:

Try this code.

```js
const options = baseUrl + 'signin/google'



$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {

  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {

    var http = [removed].protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');

    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;

  }

});



$.post(

options,

    function (response) {

        console.log(">>>> " + JSON.stringify(response));

});
```

Comment: it is specific to react native as a frontend, jhipster spring as a backend and google signin issue.